# Quiero sumar los totales de 3 grid de un reporte en reportviewer c#

Tags: c#, dataset, rdlc

me podrían ayudar?

Tengo un reporte hecho en rdlc 2008 , en el cual tengo dos datasets. Al final de cada uno, agregué el total de algunas de las columnas, pero ahora necesito realizar operaciones con el total de esas columnas de cada uno de los grids. Saben si se puede guardar en variables ese total para después realizar multiplicaciones - sumas , etc?

O que me recomiendan hacer?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.